# Creating sql view where the select is dependent on the value of two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

I want to create a view in my database, based on these three tables:
[image]

I would like to select the rows in table3 that has the highest value in `Weight`, for rows that has the same value in `Count`.

Then I want them grouped by `Category_ID` and ordered by `Date`, so that if two rows in table3 are identical, I want the newest.

Let me give you an example:

**Table1**

```
ID | Date       | UserId
1  | 2015-01-01 | 1
2  | 2015-01-02 | 1
```

**Table2**

```
ID | table1_ID | Category_ID
1  | 1         | 1
2  | 2         | 1
```

**Table3**

```
ID | table2_ID | Count | Weight
1  | 1         | 5     | 10 
2  | 1         | 5     | 20      <-- count is 5 and weight is highest
3  | 1         | 3     | 40      
4  | 2         | 5     | 10
5  | 2         | 3     | 40      <-- newest of the two equal rows
```

Then the result should be row 2 and 5 from table 3.

**PS** I'm doing this in mssql.

**PPS** I'm sory if the title is not appropriate, but I did not know how to formulate a good one.

Comment: What have you tried so far. What does "highest value in weight, for rows that has the same value in count" mean?

Comment: @JBond English is not my main language. I did not know how to explain what I meant properly, that's why I added the example. I haven't tried much, because I'm unsure where to start.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name MSSQL. I have mentioned it in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        t3.*
        ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Count] ORDER BY [Weight] DESC, Date DESC)   highest
    FROM TABLE3 t3
    INNER JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t2.Id = t3.Table2_Id
    INNER JOIN TABLE1 t1 ON t1.Id = t2.Table1_Id
) t
WHERE t.Highest = 1
```

This will group by the Count (which must be the same). Then it will determine which has the highest weight. If two of more of them have the same 'heighest' weight, it takes the one with the most recent date first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RANK() analytic function here, and give those rows a rank and than choose the first rank for each ID

Something like

```
select * 
from 
    (select 
         ID, table2_ID, Count, Weight,
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Count, Weight DESC) as Highest 
     from table3) 
where Highest = 1;
```

This is the syntax for Oracle, if you not using it look in the internet for the your syntax which should be almost the same